# How to download from FTP server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So I'm trying to make a "launcher" in visual basic. This launcher contains login forms (username/password). I have a Filezilla server up and 2 accounts. I'd like to connect with the server and download files in the background as not to disrupt work. I'm not much of a coder, but I tried to tie this up with "winSCP", what I did was only launch and connect to the server, but the user still has to enter username and password, which was entered before (with the login form).

Also how would I change the "USER" part, like with batch files when you can use "%username%" instead of actual username?

```
 If ComboBox1.Text = "Server EU #1" Then
        Process.Start("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\winscp573\WinSCP.exe", "ftp:[server IP]")
    End If
```

If at all possible I'd like to avoid using other programs and keep it as simple as possible.

**TL;DR**

1. Login with visual studio to filezilla server (FTP), not using other programs
2. upload files from main computer to the user (automatically starts uploading CERTAIN files/folders, everything running in the background as not to disrupt work, aka nothing popping up)
3. Change [USER] part of code so that it is always the correct user (like batch files use "%username%")

P.S.
maybe I could use windows build it FTP to connect and download?

Comment: why not use the Ftp classes in .NET to do what you want? Why are you trying to script it? I don't think anybody will give you everything you want - did you do some research yourself?

Comment: You're talking about writing a program, right? Visual Studio is an IDE - just a fancy text editor. It doesn't download things with FTP (in general). So what kind of program? Console? Windows Forms? What actual problem are you having?

Comment: Well Im trying to make a launcher, like games do, for example League of Legends. When I start that launcher, it automatically starts to download the latest update. this is what I want to replicate.
Im having trouble with writing the piece of code that will connect me to my server and automatically download for example all .pdf files in a certain folder. Id like this to be done in the background and not have some things pop up